# PHP - remove spaces infront of text inside of a string

Tags: php, string, spaces

Okay, this is probably a pretty basic problem but I can't solve it.

I have a String like this one: '      This is a text' and now I wan't to remove the spaces infront of the first character of the string. I tried using preg_replace but I can only remove all the spaces using that function. Does anyone have an idea how I can remove just the spaces infront of my Text?

Comment: Just use PHP's [`trim()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php) function; *done like dinner.*

Comment: Use [trim](http://php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php).

Comment: You *can* remove only leading spaces with a regular expression (just search for `/^\s+/`). But of course you don't need to.

Comment: @JayBlanchard Thanks for the hyperlink; saved me from getting the URL ;)

Comment: Googling your question's title led me to the question's closure link. Something you could have easily done.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`trim`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php):

```
echo trim(' This is a text '); // 'This is a text'
```

---

If you want to preserve any spaces at the *end* of the string, use [`ltrim`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ltrim.php):

```
echo ltrim(' This is a text '); // 'This is a text '
```

---

Similarly, although not your question, you can preserve any spaces at the *beginning* of the string by using [`rtrim`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.rtrim.php):

```
echo rtrim(' This is a text '); // ' This is a text'
```

Comment: If it it's *only* the left side you want, (for example, you wanted to keep spaces on the right side), use "left trim":

$var = ltrim($string);

Answer (score 0):

Use the `trim()` function:

```
$str = trim($str)
```

See the PHP manual: http://php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php